# `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.docx --outdir /pdf` is not working in docker image

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, libreoffice

The problem is that I am trying to convert `doc,docx` files uploaded to GCS bucket to pdf and then upload it back in GCS bucket for further processing. I am using **Ubuntu Environment** so using LibreOffice in headless mode to convert the file. The code works perfectly fine in local but when in the docker image fails due to the large file containing images in it.

This is my python code:

```py
args = [libreoffice, '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', folder, source]

process = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=timeout)
```

Which works for smaller files but hangs for larger files that contain images and do not return anything.

**NOTE: when running same code in google compute engine it worked properly.**

Comment: Hi, please provide more details about your error. Try introducing what you are trying to do? why you are using libreoffice in a docker image? What do you want to achieve? and the error or unexpected behavior that you are obtaining from tour current approach. Please also refer to [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) these guidelines will help you to improve your question. Thanks!

Comment: @EnriqueBet so problem is i m trying to convert doc,docx file uploaded to gcs bucket to pdf and the upload it back in gcs bucket for further processing . i m using ubuntu environment so using LibreOffice in headless mode to convert file, the code works perfectly fine in local. but when creating docker image and running than it fails for large file containing images in it.

Comment: Please see how does your question was edited to improve the quality of it according to your description. I encourage you to take a look at the title and use a better title for your question. Thanks